# Get Jenkins plugin dependencies auto installed

Tags: plugins, jenkins, dependencies, jenkins-plugins

I'm developing Jenkins' plugin which is dependent on another plugin (specifically MultiJob plugin, but it can be any other one of course).

Obviously, the dependency is found in POM, so I can actually use the classes of it.

The problem: if I'm trying to install my plugin in Jenkins that the dependency is not found in it Jenkins doesn't installs it automatically and upon first usage my plugin throws an exception NoClassDefFoundError, of course.

Question: can I make Jenkins to install my dependencies as prerequisites and if yes, how?

Note: I do see that other plugins somehow cause the dependencies to be installed (Git plugin for instance makes GitClient installed during its installation).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to install it? Presumably all the jars/hpis are found to compile it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since i've raised the question, but if anybody will look for something similar, here is what i've finally came up with:

Since the dependency classes are only needed in case they are really there, i've decided to use Java's **lazy linkage** behavior and actually refer the relevant classes only on demand.
So practically, made a factory that has a list of class names of interest and every time i need to process some object i'm checking it's class against this list. If matched - the class is loaded and therefore it's okay to init the linking/initiation logic.

Last one, if you plan to use such a pattern do not forget to sign those dependency plugins as **optional** in your pom.xml.